# How to mix trainable and non trainable weights inside a same layer in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to create a layer (with tensorflow.keras) which contains both trainable and non trainable weights. I tried doing so by subclassing keras.layers.Layer as in this example:

```
class MySum(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, **kwargs):
        super(MySum, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units


    def build(self, input_shape):  

        n_input = input_shape[-1]   # nb of input elements
        n_output = self.units       # nb of layer neurons  
        n_input_div_2 = input_shape[-1] // 2

        # 1. add the trainable weights
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(n_input_div_2, self.units),
                             initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),
                             trainable=True)

        # 2. add the non trainable weights
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1]-n_input_div_2, self.units),
                        initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(value=3),
                        trainable=False)

    def call(self, inputs):  
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w)
```

Unfortunately, doing so all the weights are non trainable. If I add first the non trainable weights then all the weights are trainable (it seems that the trainable flag is set according to the last weights added).
What am I missing here?

---

EDIT:
I tried to use different names as suggested by Dr. Snoopy in the build function:

```
# 1. add the trainable weights
w1 = self.add_weight(shape=(n_input_div_2, self.units),
                         initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),
                         trainable=True)

# 2. add the non trainable weights
w2 = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1]-n_input_div_2, self.units),
                    initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(value=3),
                    trainable=False)

self.w = tf.concat([w1, w2], 0)
```

But, when I try to use my layer like this:

```
custom = customLayer.MySum(1, name='somme')
my_input = keras.Input(shape=(2,), name="input")  
my_output = custom(my_input)
print(custom.get_weights())
```

I obtain via the get_weights() function:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1.]
 [3.]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)
[array([[1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32), array([[1.]], dtype=float32), array([[3.]], dtype=float32)]
```

1. Where does the [[1.],[1.]] array come from? (I would like to have only the [[1.][3.]] array)
2. I have lots of warning when training my model: ***"WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['somme/Variable:0', 'somme/Variable:0'] when minimizing the loss."***
   How does keras link my own weights (self.w) with the weights returned by get_weights()?

Note: when I create customed layers without mixing trainable and non trainable weights I don't have these issues.

Comment: You are using the same variable from both weights, this overwrites the previously defined weights, just use different variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dr. Snoopy pointed out, your first solution overwrites the previously defined weight by using the same variable name.

As to why your second solution does not work either, it is because after calling `tf.concat` on your two `tf.Variable` `w1` and `w2`, e gradient disappears. It is a known bug on Tensorflow, you can find the issue on github here : [Gradients do not exist for variables after tf.concat(). #37726](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37726)

### A Minimal reproducible example

Lets do some experiment using `tf.GradientTape` to calculate the gradient :

```
w1 = tf.Variable([1.0])
w2 = tf.Variable([3.0])
w =  tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([w1,w2],0),-1)
X = tf.random.normal((1,2))
y = tf.reduce_sum(X,1)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    r = tf.matmul(w,X)
    loss = tf.metrics.mse(y, w)
print(tape.gradient(loss, r))
```

Results in `None`.

### A possible fix

One solution is to keep the Variable separated. For your layer, with a number of `units=1`, there is this trivial replacement of `tf.matmul` :

```
w1 = tf.Variable([1.0])
w2 = tf.Variable([3.0], trainable=False)
X = tf.random.normal((1,2))
y = tf.reduce_sum(X,1)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    r = X[:,0]*w1 + X[:,1]*w2
    loss = tf.metrics.mse(y,r)
print(tape.gradient(loss, r))
```

Outputs : `tf.Tensor([-3.1425157], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)`

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! It seems to fix my problem wrt the weights. But there are still a few things I don't understand:
1) if I add a bias in my class MySum and I use it in MySum.call then I sould be able to see it outside my class calling the tf.keras function get_weight() on my layer. But I only see the weights.
2) How does tf.keras know how to compute the gradient when I create my own layer with customed weights and activation function?

Comment: @MepM I've updated my answer, the behavior was in fact due to a bug in TensorFlow. For your other questions, feel free to ask other questions on the website. I'll try to answer if I can.